# Is it possible to move a file with python, that has been uploaded with php (tmp_name in mind)?

Tags: php, python, file-upload, upload

As said in the title, I can't seem to be able to move a file with python, that has been uploaded using php.

Here is how my function is structured:

1. Make required directories (if they aren't already created)
2. Use the python move method from shutils
3. And then to finally return the final path as to input it into the database

The problem that I seem to be encountering is that php renames the file, and then when I try to move it, it keeps the same (such as 'phpb4ZbDq').

Is it possible?

EDIT:

Figured it out.

What one must do is simply add the original filename of the file (with included extension, .mp3 in my case) and concatenate it to the path

aka

shutil.move(temp, main_dir + '/' + filename)

Comment: why not do it all in python or all in php? both languages can do this

Comment: There's a module that I need (mutagen)

Comment: what ever it does, it can be done in both languages - good luck